# what is the upper bound of $\max \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i$

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, optimization, special-functions

I need to find an equation for the upper bound of $\max \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i, \; i=1, \dots N$.

where $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{x}_i$ are two vectors.

I need to find a function $f$ which holds the following inequality.

$\max \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}_i \leq \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{z}$

where $\mathbf{z}$ is a function which operates on $\mathbf{x}_i, i=1, \dots, N$

e.g

Let $\mathbf{x}_1 = \begin{pmatrix}x_{11}\\x_{12}\\x_{13}\end{pmatrix}, \; \dots, \mathbf{x}_N = \begin{pmatrix}x_{N1}\\x_{N2}\\x_{N3}\end{pmatrix}$

$\mathbf{z} = \begin{pmatrix}f(x_{11}, \dots, x_{N1})\\f(x_{12}, \dots, x_{N2})\\f(x_{13}, \dots, x_{N3})\end{pmatrix}$

for example f can be a $\max$ or $\min$ function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cauchy-Schwarz: $w^T x_i \leq ||w|| \cdot ||x_i||$

First, take the max over the right-hand side: $w^Tx_i \leq ||w|| \max_i ||x_i||$. Since this holds for all $i$ on the left-hand side, take $\max_i$ on that side, as well. So:

$$
\max_i w^T x_i \leq ||w|| \max_i ||x_i||
$$

Then let $z = f(x_1, \ldots, x_N) = \frac{\max{||x_i||}}{||w||} w$.

Comment: Thank you. But Is it possible to have f as a function only on x?

Comment: it is. $w$ is a constant, no?

Comment: $\mathbf{w}$ is a vector.

Comment: All the values of $\mathbf{x}_i, \forall i$ are known, but the values of $\mathbf{w}$ are unknown.

Comment: Yes I realize $w$ is a vector... even if its values are not known, it is still constant with respect to the max over $i$ and with respect to $f$ as defined. What you're asking now is different from the original question. You're asking for $f$ with the previous properties + that $w$ appear nowhere in $f$'s definition. Idk the answer to that.

Comment: The values of $\mathbf{w}$ do not depend on $i$.

Comment: which is why I said it is constant with respect to the max over $i$...